# Writing as integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I wanted to write $$\prod_{x=3}^9 (x)$$ so I wrote it as $$\frac{9!}{2!}$$ which I further wrote as $$\frac{\int_0 ^\infty t^9 e^{-t} dt}{\int_0 ^\infty z^2 e^{-z} dz}$$

**Is this way of writing correct?**

***Please Help***

Comment: Your product is actually $\frac {9!}{2!}$.

Comment: Yes...i was just confirming as i am new to this notation...thanks

Comment: @player3236 ... oh ya! I saw my mistake...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write out the product $\prod_{x=3}^9(x)$ in full, you should get $3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9$ which is equivalent to $\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9}{1\cdot2}$ or $\frac{9!}{2!}$ not $\frac{9!}{3!}$ so the correct use of the Pi/Gamma function would be $\frac{\int^\infty_0t^9e^{-t}dt}{\int^\infty_0z^2e^{-z}dz}$.
Other than the small error in the original, this is all equivalent.